# Shrink title background instead of 100% page width

Tags: html, css, json

I'm working on a site and have a white background behind my site title and site tagline.  However, I want the site title's background to be the width of the actual title, rather than it spanning across at 100%.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[Site](https://splitblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1394638811526)

CSS

```
.site-title {
    .site-title-font;
    color:@site-title-color;
    background-color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
.site-tagline {
    .site-tagline-font;
    color:@site-tagline-color;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

HTML/JSON

```
          <!--Site title or logo.-->
      {.section website}

        <div class="site-title" data-content-field="site-title">
          <a class="site-title" href="/">
            {.section logoImageUrl}
             <img class="logo" src="{logoImageUrl}?format=original" alt="{siteTitle}" />
            {.or}
              {siteTitle}
            {.end}
          </a>
        </div>

            <!--Site tagline.-->
            <div class="site-tagline">
            {.section siteTagLine}<div>{@}</div>{.end}
            </div>
          {.end}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add display: inline-block

```
.site-title {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #181818;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "proxima-nova";
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! Ha! Thanks very much.

Comment: This article adds some more depth to using this display property: http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/